Registration with Regasm of a library impossible
I'm testing a small dll registered in COM, I use COM because the DLL will be call by a Delphi program. Here is the simple source:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MCMTSimulator
{
public class Simulator
    {

        public int RS232(sbyte[] data)
        {
            return 6;
        }

    }
}

Then in the assembly:
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly: ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
// Le GUID suivant est pour l'ID de la typelib si ce projet est exposé à COM
[assembly: Guid("b3f59863-c1a6-448b-aaa2-2bfdf292cc27")]

I compile this with visual studio started as administrator.
Then I run the console in administrator mode:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe MCMTSimulator.dll /register /codebase /tlb

And I get "access denied" every time!
Thanks for your help

If the console is run as admin, it should work. Can you show exactly the full error you see

Sometime I become crazy. I have restart my computer for the 4th time, and now it's working!! A squere electron somewhere?? :-) Nevertheless, thanks.

Typical anti-malware induced problem.
